# Create PHP page restricted to groups Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.1

I've created a php page, but the content may only be available for a particular group Joomla.

The file is within a folder, and this folder is in the root of the site with joomla!

How do I get my php page, check the user data: UserGroupID

```
/ root
/ root / administrator
/ root / components
...
/ root / folder
/ root / folder / file.php
```

And file.php

```
$content_to_group_id = 7;

if ($group_id_user == $content_to_group_id) {
// show
} else {
// error
}
```

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/Developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Load joomla frame work to your page with following codes.

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );//this is when we are in the root
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

$user = JFactory :: getUser();//if you want to get current users details then empty params other wise pass like JFactory::getUser($user_id);
echo "<pre/>";
print_r($user)//This resulted array have the user group of the user.
```

Hope its help you..

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to utilize the Joomla framework to get the user's id, query the database for a matching record in the #__user_usergroup_map table. The code below hasn't been tested and will require you to load the Joomla framework into your script.

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$userID = $user->get('id');

// allowed group_id
$groupID = 7;

$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('user_id');
$query->from('#__user_usergroup_map');
$where->where('user_id = ' . $userID . 'and group_id = ' . $groupID); 
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->Query();
$num_rows=$db->getNumRows();

if ($num_rows === 1) {
  // only one matching record 
}
else {
  // Sorry, you aren't allowed here.
}
```

Comment: Your question is also correct, I would say that is the second part of the solution! But only one question can be marked as correct!

Answer (score 0):

Note you are using Joomla! 3+, so some of the code above my result in errors due to deprecated methods and or PHP version. Below you find some useful lines that may help you,especially the $groups variable, which returns an array of the authorized user groups. Then you just have to check your user id against the array $groups.

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$db = JFactory:: getDbo();
$groups = $user->getAuthorisedGroups();
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
```

Hope it helps.